# Showcases of formalized mathematics in a system like Coq or Lean?

Tags: formal-proofs, type-theory, computer-assisted-proofs

I have been reading about and trying out type theory based proof assistants Lean and Coq, and I have seen a few formalized proofs of basic, isolated propositions.

I am looking for examples, showcases, of a formalized body of theory of e.g. standard undergraduate texts, to showcase how one would go about setting up complex formalized theories. E.g. I'd be interested to see a formalization in a proof assistant like Lean or Coq, of the theory of groups, together with the homomorphism theorems, and so forth.

Comment: Perhaps [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311071/which-mathematical-definitions-should-be-formalised-in-lean) would be interesting for you. While looking for that question I've seen that Kevin Buzzard (who asked that question) has a [blog](https://xenaproject.wordpress.com/) about his use of Lean in his teaching, which could also be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing project called [mathlib](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib) that is formalizing a lot of maths from different areas in lean. You can look around [this folder](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/tree/master/src) to see the various topics already formalized, for example you can see in [this folder](https://github.com/leanprover-community/mathlib/tree/master/src/group_theory) which group theory results have been formalized.

It is not organized like a textbook and different topics are at very different levels, but it's one of the biggest bodies of formalized math out there!

Answer (score 0):

The systems are unlike Coq or Lean in many ways, but Mizar has the journal [Formalized Mathematics](http://mizar.org/fm/index.html) which has identifiers you can look up at, say [this list of current HTML files](http://www.mizar.org/version/current/html/) to get the original code. And Metamath is used to make the [Metamath Proof Explorer](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/mmtheorems.html). Both have an assortment of math that has been formally checked.