# datebase of formal mathematics

Tags: soft-question, math-software, formal-proofs, programming

I am learning Logic and set theory, in the process I have made some formal proofs, but this is tedious with the traditional tools. Now, I am wondering if there exists some software or something like a programming language where such formal proofs can be done. So it would be possible to create a datebase of formal proofs.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Something like http://us.metamath.org/?

Comment: There are proof assistants like Coq in which formal proofs are done. Learning to use them is a skill all its own, and it's probably not too useful. When learning logic for the first time, the most important thing is to learn the rules well enough that you can use them informally and understand how one could, in theory, transform any informal proof into a formal one.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285114/40119